# Can I calculate an aggregate duration over multiple rows with a single row per day?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, linq-to-sql, gaps-and-islands

I'm creating an Absence Report for HR.  The Absence Data is stored in the database as a single row per day (the columns are EmployeeId, Absence Date, Duration).  So if I'm off work from Tuesday 11 February 2020 to Friday 21 February 2020 inclusive, there will be 9 rows in the table:

11 February 2020 - 1 day

12 February 2020 - 1 day

13 February 2020 - 1 day

14 February 2020 - 1 day

17 February 2020 - 1 day

18 February 2020 - 1 day

19 February 2020 - 1 day

20 February 2020 - 1 day

21 February 2020 - 1 day

(see screenshot below)

[image: 6 February 2020 - 1 day]

HR would like to see a single entry in the report for a contiguous period of absence:

[image]

My question is - without using a cursor, how can I calculate the is in SQL (even more complicated because I have to do this using Linq to SQL, but I might be able to swap this out for a stored procedure.  Note that the criterion for contiguous data is adjacent working days EXCLUDING weekends and bank holidays.  I hope I've made myself clear ... apologies if not.

Comment: *"Note that the criterion for contiguous data is adjacent working days EXCLUDING weekends and bank holidays."* I assume, therefore, you have a calendar table?

Comment: Sadly I don't have a calendar table.  The Absence application is proprietary and not owned by the organisation, so I'm stuck with the existing schema.

Comment: You will **need** one for public holidays. SQL Server has no awareness of when public holidays are (and they vary vastly based on geographical locations), so you need to let it know; a Calendar table is a necessity there.

Answer (score 0):

This is a form of gaps-and-islands.  In this case, use `lag()` to see if two vacations overlap and then a cumulative sum:

```
select employee, min(absent_from), max(absent_to)
from (select t.*,
             sum(case when prev_absent_to = dateadd(day, -1, absent_from) then 0 else 1
                 end) over (partition by employee order by absent_to) as grp
      from (select t.*,
                   lag(absent_to) over (partition by employee order by absent_from) as prev_absent_to
            from t
           ) t
     ) t
group by employee, grp;
```

If you need to deal with holidays and weekends, then you need a calendar table.

Comment: Sadly I don't have a calendar table.  The Absence application is proprietary and not owned by the organisation, so I'm stuck with the existing schema.